# Rails simple user discussion self reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design, model

I want to create a simple discussion board, a discussion will contain a title, content, a user_id and a topic_id.
To allow a user to reply to a discussion I need to self reference the original discussion, though I'm not sure how to do this.

This is my migration

```
class CreateDiscussions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :discussions do |t|
      t.text :post
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :topic, index: true
      t.string :title
      t.references :discussion, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and my discussion model;

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :discussion
end
```

a user will create a disussion, another user can reply to that discussion in which I'll store the original discussion_id so I can do something like `@d = Discussion.where discussion_id: nil` to find the top-level discussions, and

```
  @d.each do |d|
     @replies = Discussion.where discussion_id: d.id
   end
```

is this along the right track?
(I don't know how to properly implement the names as described here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins)

( I've just realised that it's probably better/easier separated into two models, discussions and replies, but I'd still like to know how to do it in a single model)

Comment: Have you seen my new edit ? I fixed the issue, sorry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can structure your Discussion class as follows:

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic
  has_many :replies, class_name: "Discussion", foreign_key: "replied_to_id" 
  belongs_to :master_discussion, class_name: "Discussion", foreign_key: "replied_to_id"
end
```

Migration file:

```
class CreateDiscussions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :discussions do |t|
      t.text :post
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :topic, index: true
      t.string :title
      t.integer :replied_to_id, index: true    
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You can now use `@discussion.replies` to access replies belonging to a discussion and `@discussion.master_discussion` to access the discussion record to which this reply belongs

**EDIT**

changed:

```
t.references :discussion, index: true
```

to:

```
t.integer :replied_to_id, index: true
```

I tested and it's all working:

```
[11] pry(main)> @discussion = Discussion.create(post:"first post", title: "first discussion")
=> #<Discussion id: 3, post: "first post", title: "first discussion", replied_to_id: nil, created_at: "2014-10-23 20:15:38", updated_at: "2014-10-23 20:15:38">

[12] pry(main)> @discussion.replies << Discussion.create(post: "post to first thread",title: "reply to first thread")
=> [#<Discussion id: 4, post: "post to first thread", title: "reply to first thread", replied_to_id: 3, created_at: "2014-10-23 20:17:06", updated_at: "2014-10-23 20:17:06">]

[13] pry(main)> @discussion.replies
=> [#<Discussion id: 4, post: "post to first thread", title: "reply to first thread", replied_to_id: 3, created_at: "2014-10-23 20:17:06", updated_at: "2014-10-23 20:17:06">]

[14] pry(main)> @reply = @discussion.replies.first
[15] pry(main)> @reply.master_discussion
  Discussion Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "discussions".* FROM "discussions"  WHERE "discussions"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
=> #<Discussion id: 3, post: "first post", title: "first discussion", replied_to_id: nil, created_at: "2014-10-23 20:15:38", updated_at: "2014-10-23 20:15:38">
```

Comment: how do I create the master_discussion? Do I set master_discussion to discussion_id?

Comment: @discussion.replies gives the error                                 PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column discussions.replied_to_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "discussions".* FROM "discussions"  WHERE "discussion...
  ^
: SELECT "discussions".* FROM "discussions"  WHERE "discussions"."replied_to_id" = $1
(pry) output error: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column discussions.replied_to_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "discussions".* FROM "discussions"  WHERE "discussion...
^
: SELECT "discussions".* FROM "discussions"  WHERE "discussions"."replied_to_id" = $1>

Comment: Have you run the migration and restart the rails console/server ?

Comment: Apparently `t.references :discussion` didn't use the foreign key I had specified. so I changed the migration to use `t.integer :replied_to_id` instead. I tested and it's working. please see my edits